# TSql Contains weighed columns

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, contains

I have the following request:

```
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId
FROM V_ProductForSearch 
WHERE CONTAINS ((SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation), @KeyWords)
```

Is it possible to attribute a different weight in function of the column where the term was found. Per example, in this case it would be a weight of 0.8 for the two first columns and 0.5 for the last ones.

I know it is possible to assign a weight when we have several searched terms, but is it possible to do the same thing for columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has not implimented a way to achieve this, you can only weigh the keywords as it has been implimented. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx (Read paragraph G.)

I have tried to make an alternative way of doing this, I hope it can be used.

What i am doing is weighing SearchKeyWords = 5, PTitle = 4, PDescription = 3, Presentation = 2. These values are being summed up and ordered by

```
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId, SUM(srank) ranked 
FROM (
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId, 5 srank
FROM V_ProductForSearch  
WHERE CONTAINS ((SearchKeyWords), @KeyWords) 
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId, 4 srank
FROM V_ProductForSearch  
WHERE CONTAINS ((PTitle), @KeyWords) 
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId , 3 srank
FROM V_ProductForSearch  
WHERE CONTAINS ((PDescription), @KeyWords) 
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId, 2 srank 
FROM V_ProductForSearch  
WHERE CONTAINS ((Presentation), @KeyWords) ) a
GROUP BY Id,SearchKeyWords, PTitle, PDescription, Presentation, Category, ManufacturerId
ORDER BY SUM(srank)
```